# How to sum multiple different objects in an array using Vue.JS 3 composition API?

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, vue.js, vuejs3

I am getting started with Vue. I am struggling to calculate the sum of different elements in an object of an array.

My array looks like this:

```
const products = ref([
  { id: 4028, name: 'PÃO FRANCÊS', img: 'https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/rocky-2c5b937991b0cfc379dbf5f675740298/101448b5fafcae95596fbce5b5cc3f7f.jpg', price: 6.46 },
  { id: 4029, name: 'MOLHO DE TOMATE', img: 'https://rafasupervarejao.com.br/31563-large_default/8076809513661-molho-de-tomate-italiano-bolognese-barilla-400g.jpg', price: 6.46 },
  { id: 4030, name: 'MANTEIGA', img: 'https://rafasupervarejao.com.br/28528-large_default/7898924049365-manteiga-com-sal-reliquia-da-canastra-200g.jpg', price: 6.46 },
  { id: 4031, name: 'Feijão', img: 'https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/71T01WVZh5L._AC_SL1500_.jpg', price: 6.46 },
])
```

I am trying to sum the price and set it to totalPrice. So the array will change `totalPrice` as below:

```
id: 4028,
      name: "PÃO FRANCÊS",
      totalPrice: 6.46,

id: 4029,
      name: "MOLHO DE TOMATE",
      totalPrice: 12.92,
```

I believe I need to use something like the below to sum them, however I cannot figure out how to do this!

```
const totalPrice = products.price += products.price
```

How do I calculate the sum of the price and set it as the totalPrice?

I have traveled SO and find similar threads however nothing that I can get to work with my issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To calculate the sum of `price` values of all `products`, you could use [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) in a `computed`:

```js
const totalPrice = computed(() => {
  return products.value.reduce((acc, product) => {
    return acc + product.price
  }, 0)
})
```

Shorter syntax:

```js
const totalPrice = computed(() =>
  products.value.reduce((sum, item) => sum + item.price, 0)
)
```

Comment: Yeah, i personally prefer one-liners, but the OP is new user so i added explicit returns for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you are specifically asking about Vue because you want to calculate the total price dynamically, so that it updates when products are added or removed from the `product` list?

In Vue, you do this with a [computed property](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html):

```
const totalPrice = computed( () => products.value.reduce((total, product) => total + product.price, 0))
```

Since `products` is reactive, Vue detects when it changes and will automatically recalculate `totalPrice`